# Ошибка "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'GenericsHW.MyList<T>.array' "

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, объясните пожалуйста, почему возникает ошибка:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property GenericsHW.MyList.array.

---

Ведь в методе `Contains(T item)` организован точно такой же цикл, но ошибки нет; с чем это связано? Причём, если я сделаю `array` статическим, то всё ок (почему нужно писать static?). Заранее спасибо :)

---

```
namespace GenericsHW
{
    interface IMyList<T>
    {
        void Add(T a);
        T this[int index] { get; }
        int Count { get; }
        void Clear();
        bool Contains(T item);
    }

    class MyList<T>:IMyList<T>
    {
        T[] array = null;
        delegate void ShowArrayElements();
        public MyList()
        {
            array = new T[0];
        }
        public  int Count
        {
            get { return array.Length; }
        }

        public void Add(T a)
        {
            T[] temp = new T[array.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                temp[i] = array[i];
            temp[array.Length] = a;
            array = temp;
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return array[index]; }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            array = new T[0];
        }

        public  bool Contains(T item)
        {
            foreach (T ar in array)
            {
                if (ar.Equals(item))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Количество элементов массива:{0}\n", array.Length);
        }

        private ShowArrayElements ShowArray = () =>
        {
            foreach (T ar in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ",ar);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: а что непонятно в самой ошибке? _A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property_ - при инициализации полей не могут использоваться не статические поля, методы и свойства

Comment: перенесите инициализацию в конструктор и все заработает

Comment: @Grundy: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, о, я тебя как раз хотел позвать сюда :-) интересно почему внутренность присваиваемого делегата, тоже не должна использовать нестатические поля, ведь она же только присваивается, а не выполняется :)

Comment: @VladD, ну потому-то надо ж как-то объяснить :-) а одна строчка как-то не то :) ну и я точно помню уже было про инициализацию полей

Comment: @Grundy: Потому что в этот момент класс неинициализирован, и значения полей непонятно какие. А если поле используется, то использующий код может именно в этот момент увидеть неправильное значение. То, что в данном конкретном случае код не читает значение поля, компилятор установить и не пытается (в общем случае это невозможно).

Comment: @Grundy: Проще наверное превратить этот код в обыкновенную функцию?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40533/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Comment: @Grundy: Сейчас не могу, сижу на митинге, писать с телефона в чате неудобно. :)

Comment: а что за митинг? :-) потом в чате глянешь :):):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

---

> При инициализации полей не могут использоваться не статические поля, методы и свойства

Ясно говорит, что **нельзя** использовать не статические члены класса при использовании инициализатора, то есть когда значение полю присваивается напрямую в теле класса при объявлении, а не в конструкторе.

Обойти данную проблему можно перенеся инициализацию данного делегата в конструктор, например так:

```
private ShowArrayElements ShowArray;

public MyList()
{
    array = new T[0];
    ShowArray = () =>
    {
        foreach (T ar in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ",ar);
        }
    };
}
```

---

Ссылки на статью Эрика Липперта, поясняющую данное поведение:

1. [Первая часть](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/)
2. [Вторая часть](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/)