# Нестатическая переменная при создании массива

Tags: c#

хочу сделать мультиязычность для некоторых переменных. В другом классе инициализирую для каждого пользователя класс MyVariables передавая в параметре значение выбираемого им языка.

```
  public class MyVariables {
        private const string RU_LANG = "RU";
        private const string EN_LANG = "EN";

        private string language = RU_LANG;

        public MyVariables (string lang) {
            language = lang;
        }

        public string one_message {
            get {
                switch (language) {
                    case EN_LANG:
                        return "Message";
                    case RU_LANG:
                    default:
                        return "Сообщение";
                }
            }
        }

        public string[] messages = new string[] { one_message };
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при создании массива сообщений возникает ошибка `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property` на переменную *one_message*. Массив нужно сделать именно в классе MyVariables.

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529109/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-pr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенесите инициазацию в конструктор.

```
public string[] messages;

public MyVariables (string lang)
{
    language = lang;
    messages = new string[] { one_message };
}
```

Но я так и не понял, зачем вам массив.

Если по-простому, на 2 языка, то бы сделал как-то так. Немного костыльно, на зато просто.

```
public enum Language
{
    EN, RU
}

public static class Localization
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Language, string[]> _data = new()
    {
        [Language.RU] = new string[]
        {
            "Имя",
            "Сообщение"
        },
        [Language.EN] = new string[]
        {
            "Name",
            "Message"
        }
    };

    public static Language Language = Language.EN;

    public static string Name => _data[Language][0];
    public static string Message => _data[Language][1];
}
```

```
Localization.Language = Language.RU;
string message = Localization.Message;
```

Comment: Здесь у всех переменных static, не получится ли, что при задании у первого пользователя языка, потом язык задается у второго пользователя, то у первого изменится?

Comment: @Александр это же локализация, просто строки. Как у вас тот же Message может быть переведен по-разному у разных пользователей? Никак. Но я всего-лишь показал, как это максимально просто можно сделать, но смею заметить, что это решение имеет свои играничения, и далеко от тех, что используются в серьезных проектах.

Comment: @Александр если один юзер русский, второй английский, то вам достаточно просто применить язык при входе пользователя в приложение.